# Does Body.json parse run off the event loop?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

There are plenty of questions surround `Body.json()` on stack overflow but I couldn't find one that answers my specific question.

If I run `JSON.parse()`, this will block the event loop until it has completed parsing.

`fetch()` will fetch a resource for me entirely off of the event loop, returning a Promise which schedules the callback to the event loop only when the request has completed (I believe).

`Body.json()` also returns a promise. Does that mean it makes the call to `JSON.parse()` off of the event loop and only schedule the callback when the object has completed parsing?

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse isn't necessarily called asynchronously.
Asynchronous .json returns a Promise because result returned from Request promise doesn't contain the response body and .json needs to download the response body in order to parse it

Comment: It's more *it needs to read the stream of data* than "*it needs to download the response body*". The data has already been downloaded at the time you consume the Request body.

Comment: So `JSON.parse` is called on the main event loop thread, essentially blocking drawing of the UI?

Comment: @Cheetah `JSON.parse` is not called at all. The same underlying function than the one this method uses will probably be called, but the browser won't use the method you have access to, and not from the main loop thread no. Now, will it block the UI? Hard to tell, it's implementation and device dependent..

Comment: @Kaiido - this was the answer I was expecting (implementation specific)...I guess its highly likely that the json parsing will be done on a background thread.